# Do some work on a node.js Readable stream before it is passed on

Tags: node.js, stream, iconv

I want to read data from a file within a zip file and post this data in smaller chunks to a server. As the file is pretty big, I want to use streams in node.js.

I got it working using `yauzl` for reading from zip and `readline` so I don't have to take care of line endings myself (it's a CSV file). But one problem remains: The data in the zip file is encoded in `LATIN1` and I need to post it as `UTF8`. With the help of `iconv-lite` I can properly convert the readablestream to UTF8 on console:

```
rd.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(iconv.decodeStream(data, 'LATIN1'));
});
```

Now my problem is that I would like to use `readLine` which expects the following configuration:

```
var rd = readline.createInterface({
    input: readStream,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false
});
```

So my idea was to combine `decodeStream` and `encodeStream` so I get a stream again and can pipe it in properly encoded UTF8 to `readline`.

```
readStream.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('LATIN1').pipe(iconv.encodeStream('utf8'))
```

but I fail to see how I could either use this in the `readline` configuration or "end" the pipe in a variable which I can give to `readline` as `ìnput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was so close, the solution is pretty simple:

```
      var rd = readline.createInterface({
          input: readStream.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('LATIN1')).pipe(iconv.encodeStream('utf8')),
          output: process.stdout,
          terminal: false
      });
```